# PhantomJS does not load the dynamic content of an url

Tags: javascript, dom, web-scraping, phantomjs

I am trying to use PhantomJS to get the html source (actually the title would be enough) of webpages which are dynamically generated, such as this one:

[LM386N-1/NOPB Texas Instruments | Mouse](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Texas-Instruments/LM386N-1-NOPB/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvu8NZDyZ4K0WQkiHQxR2Zd)

I have tried several scripts that i found on the internet, but none of them would retrieve the proper content (title is empty). Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried something along these lines (with some modifications to output to console):

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://google.com', function () {
    console.log(page.content);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

also this:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();  
page.open('http://www.google.com', function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to access network');
    } else {
        var p = page.evaluate(function () {
            return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML
        });
        console.log(p);
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```

also this:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');
page.open('https://www.somesite.com/page.aspx', function () {
    page.evaluate(function(){

    });

    page.render('export.png');
    fs.write('1.html', page.content, 'w');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

also this:

```
page.open(address, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
        phantom.exit();
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            page.render(output);
            phantom.exit();
        }, 1000); // Change timeout as required to allow sufficient time 
    }
});
```

Comment: Please, show what you've tried.

Comment: last one have to work

Comment: Have you tried it on this specific web page?

Comment: Have you increased the timeout in your last example? Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-1_phantomerrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: PhantomJS 2.1.1

I increased the timeout up to 20 seconds. Same result. I will register the events when I get some time.